# How to run php artisan serve command

Tags: laravel

Can someone help me? I'm trying to create a new project using Laravel, but when I run the `php artisan serve` command, it doesn't work. It they got stuck like in the picture below.

I try to reinstall XAMPP and it is still not working
[image]

Comment: Is there no response from `php artisan serve`? Run `php artisan` only and show the result

Comment: Add php excutable in windows path. Then it works.

Comment: First of all, have you created a Laravel project?
`php artisan serve` is a Laravel command, so it can only be used if php exists and Laravel is installed.

Comment: I think the official site will help you get started with Laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using git bash instead of cmd terminal.

Check if the composer and PHP are fine:
in terminal type these 2 commands

```
php -v
composer
```

Also, when you create a new project run these first

```
npm install
composer install
npm run dev

php artisan serve
```

If this doesn't work try this:
Go to xampp/htdocs and run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp 8.*
```

this will install the laravel latest version 8 app. Then try the commands above.